# Htaccess 404 redirection is break with multiple slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with my website and .htaccess file.
In my htaccess, I have many pretty url and config use for cache and other.

With my pretty url, I add:

ErrorDocument 404 /pages/index.php

It works BUT if I have https://mywebsite.com/itsnotarealroute --> it's okay, go on index

If I have https://mywebsite.com/itsnotarealroute/blabla/blabla/ --> problem, I have my index page WITHOUT style (only my css, because bootstrap is good).

An idea to fix that ?
We can use a rule in .htaccess file to say "If we have more than two / afer my domain name, redirect in index" ?

Comment: Are the includes for css using relative paths, or absolute? You should use absolute, so that any buried depth, will result in it pulling the right file.

Comment: Thank's for your reply,

So, I use absolute path, like this for example:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../prod/app.min.css">

I want use my htaccess like a router, this is okay for serve all pages, but for 404 it's poor...

Do you know a rule who redirect if all Redirections in htaccess it's not strictly the same that implicit domain name ?
(just check string after domain name)

Thank's